# Does Retrofit support websocket by now?

Tags: java, android, websocket, retrofit, retrofit2

I know that it was a work in progress and it was supposed to become a thing in version 2.1, which is the latest version.

So, is it a thing ready now? Couldn't find any info on that topic.

And if it is a thing already, how would use I it?

Comment: I think it does not support web sockets yet since it's not being mentioned in its changelog: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Hopefully on 2.2.

Comment: OkHttp supports WebSockets now. Check out this simple tutorial https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-use-websockets-on-android-with-okhttp-ba5f00aea988

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit is built on top of OkHttp, and OkHttp supports WebSockets starting from the version 3.5, [more on this here](https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelogs/changelog_3x/#version-350).

For an example, you can see the following answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416209/how-to-create-simple-okhttp3-websocket-connection).