# Sending messages from Android Websocket client

Tags: java, android, http, websocket, okhttp

I want to send a message from Android okhttp3 websocket client, not just echoing the messages coming from the server. here is my websocket class:

```
 // Websocket
 public final class EchoWebSocketListener extends WebSocketListener {
     private static final int NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;
     @Override
     public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
         webSocket.send(message);
     }
     @Override
     public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
         printer("text");
     }
     @Override
     public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
         webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null);
     }
     @Override
     public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {

     }
     public void send(WebSocket webSocket) {
       webSocket.send(finalMessage);
     }
 }
```

And here is how I call it from the onCreate method:

```
client= new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(Url).build();
EchoWebSocketListener listener = new EchoWebSocketListener();
webso = myClient.newWebSocket(request, listener);
client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
```

I tried to make an object to the class and call a function I named it 'send':

```
EchoWebSocketListener object = new EchoWebSocketListener ()
object.send(webso)
```

But that's not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create simple okhttp3 websocket connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416209/how-to-create-simple-okhttp3-websocket-connection)

Comment: Alternative way without RxJava https://stackoverflow.com/a/46628736/7377682

Answer (score 0):

recommend you this way [RxWebSocket](https://github.com/dhhAndroid/RxWebSocket)